# Running a VPN through Debian into a router

Tags: debian, vpn, ethernet

I will soon have a file server running Debian, and this server has 2 Ethernet ports. I recently came up with the idea that one Ethernet port can come as an 'input' from my actual connection, and the other one can be an 'output' cloaked in a VPN, which would then enter a switch or router, so any computer to connect to the network through that switch or router had their connection automagically run through a VPN. Is this possible? (I don't know loads about VPNs, so sorry if I make any mistakes.)

Comment: yes, it is, depending on your VPN vendor, he might even given you the necessary configuration or installation script/program [for linux].

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Depending on how you want to configure your VPN you don't need a second interface. A VPN is basically an encrypted tunnel. I suggest that you take a look at OpenVPN (https://openvpn.net/). It's a nice tool, very easy to use and configure, very well documented and compatible with a lot of operating systems.